# Using jQuery for Media Queries When CSS Is Not An Option

Tags: jquery, css, resize, window, media-queries

**EDIT:**

I have made a JSFiddle for this... but I don't think it will work right because of (window).resize(); I havn't played with JSFiddle much so I have a feeling I did this wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/beefchimi/uhw3D/25/

If anyone can help with this problem, I would **really appreciate it**.

---

So I have been struggling to find the absolute best way to reproduce CSS Media Queries with jQuery. I use CSS Media Queries almost exclusively when I can, but I'm dealing with a problem right now where I need to be able to calculate a value dynamically and apply it to an element on window resize.

Using the code below, I can check the window width at every 1 pixel increment. Firstly, I wonder if this is good performance wise, and if instead would there be a way to only execute the function when we move from breakpoint to breakpoint (480 / 768 / 1024) rather than every pixel along the way.

**My problem is this however:**

I am checking to see how many elements in the current layout have the CSS property of left: 0; and then I multiply the number of elements by 240px and apply that as the height value for a container.

Below 720px, the height for this element needs to be 'auto'. This works fine. But if I am going up from 320px, and I hit my first breakpoint (720px), I get the right height applied to my container, but once I hit the breakpoint above that (960px), the height never updates. I am wondering what I am doing wrong that is preventing the new value from being calculated and applied.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function checkWidth() {

        var windowSize = $(window).width();
        var elementCount = $('#casestudy-content article').filter(function() { return $(this).position().left === 0 }).length;

        if ( windowSize >= 720 && windowSize <= 959 ) {

            console.log("Greater than 720 and less than 960");

            console.log(elementCount);

            $('#casestudy-content').css('height', elementCount * 240 + 'px');

        }

        else if ( windowSize >= 960 && windowSize <= 1199 ) {

            console.log("Greater than 960 and less than 1200");

            console.log(elementCount);

            $('#casestudy-content').css('height', elementCount * 240 + 'px');

        }

        else if ( windowSize >= 1200 ) {

            console.log("Greater than or equal to 1200");

            console.log(elementCount);

            $('#casestudy-content').css('height', elementCount * 240 + 'px');

        }

        else {

            $('#casestudy-content').css('height', 'auto');

        }

    }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();

    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

So I discovered that, if I remove CSS transitions on these elements, my function works perfectly.

Interestingly, my console.log(elementCount) reports the correct value the moment I hit the breakpoint, so I would think that should mean I don't have to worry about the transition time, but apparently so. How can I go about delaying this function so that I can keep the transitions? If my transitions take 0.2s, I need to delay my function from firing by that much. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

**(execute the function when we move from breakpoint to breakpoint)**

Save into variable at what breakpoint you currently are:

```
var breakpoint;
function checkWidth() {
{...}
if ( windowSize >= 720 && windowSize <= 959 && breakpoint != 720) {
        breakpoint = 720;
} else if ( windowSize >= 960 && windowSize <= 1199 && breakpoint != 960) {
        breakpoint = 960;
} etc..
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uhw3D/47/

**(but once I hit the breakpoint above that (960px), the height never updates)**

Of course the `section` height wont change when the window size is greater than 500px because there will be only 3 rows (100px x 3 = 300px height) and the maximum width of the `section` is always 500px. (5 boxes per row) and you have 14 boxes. *do the calculation.*

**(How can I go about delaying this function)**

i don't know why do you need this, but you can use `setTimeout()`

you can do something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    setTimeout(checkWidth, 200); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
 });
```

on window resize the function will be fired after 0.2s

I hope that I did understand what do you mean or else please explain more what do you want to do.

Comment: Firstly, I want to thank you for replying with such an in-depth response. I really appreciate this. My JSFiddle is different than what is actually in production, and I see now that I made a mistake with the fiddle by using 100px squares instead of the 240px squares in my actual project. So thats my bad. The timeout function is because of the CSS transitions, and it taking 0.2ms for the squares to transition position. Anyways, I am still having some issues making all of this work but your response has helped clarify a few things. I plan to revisit this soon with, hopefully, a solution. Thanks.